# Can't Show database on XAMPP-> mysql to java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I am using XAMPP->Mysql to create database and using Netbeans IDE 8.1 fro create java

[image: My XAMPP Control Panel pic]

[image: Student database pic] 
My Code

```
//default package
//1st step
import java.sql.*;

public class DemoJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
          String Query = "Select * from Student";
          //2nd step  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          //3rd step
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student", "root", "0");
          //4th step
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
          //5th step
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);
            rs.next();
            String name = rs.getString("sname");
            System.out.println(name);

          //6th step
          con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

Why it didn't show output name ? It just show 
"BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)" in netbeans output

Comment: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" indicates you built the code, but maybe you didn't run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the correction of your code to loop through the `ResultSet`, you also need to correct your connection string as shown below:

Considering that your MySQL is running on the default MySQL port 3306 (which I see that you already are), the connection string needs to be updated.

Also saw that password for the user root is '0', is it really the password?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Student";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "root", "0");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        //Loop to retrieve tuple(s) from the ResultSet rs
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("sname");
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Also ensure to have your `MySQL Connector/J` jar file to be present in your CLASSPATH to not to face any reference issues.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: when I change to "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/student", "root", ""); , it's worked..!. Didn't it set by default port in MySQL ?

Comment: It's by design, you need to mention the port number in your connection string

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the `ResultSet` to get the tuples or rows. So while looping you retrieve whatever data or field you want to get. try:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String Query = "Select * from Student";
            //2nd step  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //3rd step
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student", "root", "0");
            //4th step
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            //5th step
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

            //Loop to retrieve tuple(s) from the ResultSet rs
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("sname");
                System.out.println(name);
            }

            //6th step
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**NOTE** if by default you did not change the password of the `root` user it is just the empty String (thus `""` and not `"0"`). Other than that you know what you are doing.

Comment: It's still show run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: take note of the **NOTE** part of my answer, if it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you running or you are just building the project? If you are just building, you can run using `SHIFT+F6` to run this file only.

Comment: Should I change jdbc:mysql://localhost/student to jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/student ?

Comment: Mysql is running on port `3306` according to your xampp so if anything, you rather change it to `3306`. I hope you have also added the mysql java driver jar file to libraries.

Comment: And have you changed the password to `""` as in `("jdbc:mysql://localhost/student", "root", "");` by removing the zero (0)?

Comment: I **noticed** you caught An exception but you didn't do anything there.In the `catch` block can you put this line there: `e.printStackTrace();` to see the error when an exception is caught.

Comment: I got this, I change "jdbc:mysql://localhost/student", "root", "0"); to "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student", "root", ""); and it's work..!!

Comment: if you had followed my answer and comment, you would have solved the problem. I talked about removing the zero (`"0"`) in the password column. And when you asked whether to use port `8080`, i said rather use `3306`. My problem is learn to put things together to solve problems, thank you.